# Extensional flow of a long thin thread

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My question is simply how the highlighted equations at the bottom of the following article are obtained. In particular I cannot seem to understand where the term containing external pressure $p_{ext}$ comes from in the first equation, and where the second equation comes from (here $\mu$ is dynamic viscosity and $p$ the internal pressure). A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are referring is from using absolute pressure rather than gauge pressure, and is the result of integrating the external pressure vectorially over the external surface from z to z + dz.  If the area were not changing, the pressure contribution would have no axial component, and would be zero.

The 2nd equation is just from the 3D version of Newton's law of viscosity.  The p in this equation is not the external pressure, and is determinate only from considering the boundary conditions (and is equal to $p_{ext}$ only at the boundary.  For an incompressible fluid, it is not the same as the pressure determined from the equation of state, and only represents an isotropic contribution to the stress tensor.

INTEGRATION OF EXTERNAL PRESSURE OVER SURFACE

The external pressure acts normal to the filament surface.  The unit outwardly directed normal to the filament surface is given by $$\mathbf{n}=\frac{\mathbf{i_r}-\frac{dr}{dz}\mathbf{i_z}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{dz}\right)^2}}$$So, the force per unit area that the external pressure exerts on the filament surface is $$-P_{ext}\mathbf{n}=\frac{-\mathbf{i_r}+\frac{dr}{dz}\mathbf{i_z}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{dz}\right)^2}}P_{ext}$$The radial component of this force per unit area integrates to zero, and the axial component in the positive z direction is $$\frac{\frac{dr}{dz}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{dz}\right)^2}}P_{ext}$$The differential area of surface upon which this force acts between z and z + dz is $$2\pi r\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{dz}\right)^2}dz$$So the axial component of force that the external pressure exerts on the filament between z and z + dz is $$2\pi r\frac{dr}{dz}dzP_{ext}$$So, dividing by dz in the force balance gives $$P_{ext}2\pi r\frac{dr}{dz}=P_{ext}\frac{dA}{dz}$$

As far as the derivation of the 2nd highlighted equation is concerned, the development is too extensive to present here.  For the full. derivation of this tensorial equation, see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 1

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still unsure on a few details, so I would appreciate a complete derivation of the printed results. Thanks

Comment: Your request is rather broad.  Any specific relationships you would particularly want to focus on?

Comment: Ideally, a mathematical proof of the integration of external pressure over the surface and the second highlighted result. You state it results from the '3D version of Newton's law of viscosity', but specifically where does this come into it? I know the 2D version, but I am having trouble seeing how it can be extended. A detailed explanation and some mathematical support on this point would be helpful.

Comment: See my extension to the answer I gave.

Comment: Thank you once again. One thing I wouldn't mind clearing up is precisely how the radial component integrates to 0? Could you please derive this fact in your answer?

Comment: The unit vector in the radial direction is a function of $\theta$ so, when you integrate around the circumference of the filament, it integrates to zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't follow the $\theta$ dependence. Could amend your answer to show this integration of the $\mathbf{i}_{\mathbf{r}}$ component wrt $\theta$ mathematically?

Comment: At a specified value of z, how does the direction of the radial unit vector vary with position around the circumference of the filament?

Comment: Ok, that makes it easier to visualise, but is there a rigorous treatment of this using $\int d\theta$?

Comment: $\mathbf{i_r}=\mathbf{i_x}\cos{\theta}+\mathbf{i_y}\sin{\theta}$ What do you get when you integrate this with respect to $\theta$?